# regex with findall multiple patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string 
s = "We are 'Champion' of 'The Team' if we got 0x12 to 0x34 correct answers"

I want to get a list ['Champion','The Team','0x12','0x34']

Here is what I have tried:

```
k = re.findall(r'(\'\w+\')|(0x\w+)',s)
```

but I get this instead

```
[("'Champion'", ''), ('', '0x12'), ('', '0x34')]
```

How do I fix my code ?

Comment: Just edited my question, your answer is valid solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `(...)` is a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping), it makes your match return a tuple containing the strings that matched the sub-regexs between `(...)`.

You can use `(?:...)` instead for your group to be non-capturing. Or in this case, you can just remove parentheses altogether.

```
re.findall(r"'[^']+'|0x\w+",s)
# ["'Champion'", "'The Team'", '0x12', '0x34']
```

Note that if you expect a fixed number of match, you could actually use capturing group to solve your problem.

```
re.match(r".*?'([^']+)'.*?'([^']+)'.*?(0x\w+).*?(0x\w+)",s).groups()
# ("Champion", "The Team", '0x12', '0x34')
```

Comment: Or, heck, just remove the groups entirely.

Comment: is it needed to escape single quotes inside double quotes? `re.findall(r"'[^']+'|0x\w+",s)` should work too

Comment: @Sundeep correct, I was using single quote at first, got annoyed by this, but forgot to remove escape